# Повреждена файловая система диска с ОС. Что делать?

Tags: файловая-система

Нагуглил, что можно сделать так:
диск С -- свойства -- сервис -- выполнить проверку. Этот вариант не канает, т.к. диск используется (на нём система win7). Как быть?

Comment: Установить расписание проверки после перезагрузки! Дочитывать нужно что система предлагает сделать! Не буду натупливать по поводу что вопрос на другой форум, сам понимаю что там все мертво...

Comment: ну он выкидывает окошко с 2мя кнопками. "Расписание проверки диска" и "Отмена". Жму на 1ю - ничего не происходит. Щас перезагружусь. Может чего сделает оО

Comment: многоуважаемый человек, который оставил коммент до меня. Мне, рядовому пользователю, неважно куда этот вопрос. Мне ответили и проблему я решил. За это я и люблю хэшкод. @Palmervan, преобразуй коммент в ответ. Зачту) ещё и заплюсую. Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win+R

Cmd

chkdsk C: /F /X /R

Нажимаем Y, перезагружаемся.